# Show text column wise in textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

Is there any way that i can show my text in column wise like:

> ```
> 1   5
> 2   6
> 3   7
> 4   8
> ```

Like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="mytextbox" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

This is my `TextBox`. I am getting text from a service which is string and set in this text box well that is not an issue. Issue is how can i display multiple text in column wise as I mention above?

Comment: if you would wrap your text in a collection, you could do this easy with an itemscontrol and the right ItemsPanel eg wrappanel

Comment: sorry blindmeis i didnot get your answer ...

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBox x:Name="Mytextbox" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         Text="1&#x09;5&#x0d;&#x0a;2&#x09;6&#x0d;&#x0a;3&#x09;7&#x0d;&#x0a;4&#x09;8">
</TextBox>
```

Also you can specify text in code like in the example:

```
Mytextbox.Text = "1\t3" + Environment.NewLine + "2\t4";
```

Answer (score 2):

@omeriqbal: to explain my comment. create a collection from your string

```
 this.MyText = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4",...};
```

instead of the textbox you could use an itemscontrol

```
 <ItemsControl itemsSource="{Binding MyText}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Local:UniformGrid2 Orientation="Vertical" Rows="6" />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

if you want a fix rowsize you can create you own uniformgrid

```
public class UniformGrid2 : UniformGrid
{
    private int _columns;
    private int _rows;

    #region Orientation

    /// <summary>
    /// Orientation Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
        StackPanel.OrientationProperty.AddOwner(typeof(UniformGrid2),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((Orientation)Orientation.Horizontal,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Orientation property.
    /// </summary>
    public Orientation Orientation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
        else
            return ArrangeOverrideVertical(arrangeSize);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        else
            return MeasureOverrideVertical(constraint);
    }

    private Size ArrangeOverrideVertical(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Rect finalRect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, arrangeSize.Width / ((double)_columns), arrangeSize.Height / ((double)_rows));
        double height = finalRect.Height;
        double totalHeight = arrangeSize.Height - 1.0;
        foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
        {
            element.Arrange(finalRect);
            if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                finalRect.Y += height;
                if (finalRect.Y >= totalHeight)
                {
                    finalRect.X += finalRect.Width;
                    finalRect.Y = 0.0;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }

    private Size MeasureOverrideVertical(Size constraint)
    {
        UpdateComputedValuesVertical();
        Size availableSize = new Size(constraint.Width / ((double)_columns), constraint.Height / ((double)_rows));
        double width = 0.0;
        double height = 0.0;
        int i = 0;
        int count = base.InternalChildren.Count;
        while (i < count)
        {
            UIElement element = base.InternalChildren[i];
            element.Measure(availableSize);
            Size desiredSize = element.DesiredSize;
            if (width < desiredSize.Width)
            {
                width = desiredSize.Width;
            }
            if (height < desiredSize.Height)
            {
                height = desiredSize.Height;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return new Size(width * _columns, height * _rows);
    }

    private void UpdateComputedValuesVertical()
    {
        _columns = Columns;
        _rows = Rows;
        // Ignore FirstColumn property
        FirstColumn = 0;

        if (_rows == 0 || _columns == 0)
        {
            int visibleChildren = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int count = base.InternalChildren.Count;
            while (i < count)
            {
                UIElement element = base.InternalChildren[i];
                if (element.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    visibleChildren++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (visibleChildren == 0)
            {
                visibleChildren = 1;
            }
            if (_columns == 0)
            {
                if (_rows > 0)
                {
                    _columns = (visibleChildren + (_rows - 1)) / _rows;
                }
                else
                {
                    _columns = (int)Math.Sqrt((double)visibleChildren);
                    if ((_columns * _columns) < visibleChildren)
                    {
                        _columns++;
                    }
                    _rows = _columns;
                }
            }
            else if (_rows == 0)
            {
                _rows = (visibleChildren + (_columns - 1)) / _columns;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are AcceptsTab boolean property in Textbox allow you to have tab in string and when you want to type in a Textbox and press the tab key the Textbox focus don't lost and in the text the tab space appear and after saving it to database or variable and assign it to the Textbox you have your tabs.

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="70"/>
```